# How do I center a bootstrap icon properly AND add space between it and a P element above it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm incorporating some bootstrap icons into my HTML page. I was able to center two of the ones I have now by adding **style="text-align: center"** to the DIV I've created around it. I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it but correct me if I'm wrong on that.

My issue now is I'm trying to create space between another icon and a P element above it but padding-top seems to not work. I've managed to create space between the first icon and the headers above and below it by adding padding to the headers in the CSS stylesheet but even with that I could be doing it the wrong way even though it worked.

[First Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd63z.png)
[Second Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xTjG.png)

How do I go about adding space between the second icon and P element above it correctly? I've added imagine above to show what I'm talking about. I'm new to HTML and coding so bare with me.

```css
html {
  background-color: #85BDA6;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}

#header-2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#header-5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#header-6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-top: 50px;
 
}

#pricing {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block
   
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  
}

#email {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}

#submit {
  height: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
padding-right: 15px;
background-color: grey;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;

}

.nav-options {
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  display: inline;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-options:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bi bi-truck {

    display: block;
    margin: auto;    
}

.bi bi-emoji-smile {
  
}

@media (min-width: 500px;) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-smile" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on bootstrap spacing:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Bootstrap icons do exist: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/ :)